# Running SQL in one transaction has different results to running separately

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I can't work out why this is the case, but if I run:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    ALTER TABLE [TABLE NAME] DISABLE TRIGGER [TRIGGER NAME];

    -- Some query

    ALTER TABLE [TABLE NAME] ENABLE TRIGGER [TRIGGER NAME];
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Where 'some query' depends on the trigger being disabled, I get an error (since the trigger hasn't successfully been disabled).

However, if I run the alter statements separately, it's fine.

I've tried `DISABLE TRIGGER` syntax instead, and I've tried `BEGIN` and `END` instead of `BEGIN TRANSACTION`etc.

What am I misunderstanding here? Why do these alter statements not appear to alter 'in time'?

### EDIT

I'd like to rephrase the question in favour of clarity to accompany the bounty:

**Why must we separate batches of DDL and DML?**

Comment: `Where 'some query' depends on the trigger being disabled, I get an error (since the trigger hasn't successfully been disabled)`.in first query you have provided,you are disabling it..

Comment: @TheGameiswar - correct, since the query depends on it being disabled.

Comment: your ask is not clear..Can you  please elaborate

Comment: `I get an error (since the trigger hasn't successfully been disabled).`.can you share the error and trigger status from sys.triggers

Comment: I'm not sure I can be any clearer here. `I get an error (since the trigger hasn't successfully been disabled).`. The error is that the trigger hasn't been disabled. And my query depends on that trigger being disabled.

Comment: Can you share repro for us to test

Comment: Maybe this will help - https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1591/disabling-a-trigger-for-a-specific-sql-statement-or-session/

Comment: Thanks Joe C, that certainly does help. but I'm more concerned with why it doesn't work as opposed to how I can work around it.

Comment: Hello JayMee - i just executed the same script as you posted on my MSSQL2014 and it was executed successfully. Is it possible that the error you are receiving is not the actual root cause? maybe the DML operation fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are executing them in the same batch/statement, you are altering table AFTER sql server has compiled your sql statement.

1. SQL Server compiles your statement (including all the individual DDL
   and DML commands in the batch)
2. SQL Server alters your TABLE to disable trigger
3. SQL Server runs your "query", but it is compiled to assume there was
   a trigger there, so the trigger runs.
4. SQL Server alters your TABLE to enable trigger

To solve this, you can still do it within a transaction, but you will need to separate into batches.  Insert "GO" between each statement if running from SSMS or similar tool, or call individual SQL statement if calling from code.

Comment: The notion of script compilation was what I was missing. Thanks very much.

Comment: I've awarded the bounty (thanks again!), but would love it if you could elaborate on point 3 please? Basically, how are those assumptions tracked 'under the hood'?

Comment: When you run a query batch in SQL Server, it creates an execution plan for that query batch before executing that plan.  When there is a trigger that is executed because of your queries, the execution of the trigger is part of the execution plan.  You can see this in SQL Server Mgmt Studio if you turn on Query | Include Actual Execution Plan, and run a statement that would fire a trigger.  You'll see both your query AND the trigger execution plans in the results.  Think of the trigger as a macro that gets expanded at compile time, rather than run-time. Does this help?

Comment: Perfect mate, understood. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

Mixing DDL and DML in transactions is not advised as it can produce undesired results:

```
ALTER TABLE [TABLE NAME] DISABLE TRIGGER [TRIGGER NAME];
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    -- Some query

COMMIT TRANSACTION
ALTER TABLE [TABLE NAME] ENABLE TRIGGER [TRIGGER NAME];
```